# Downloading Files in Background with Backgroundworker and byte[]

Tags: c#, wpf, download, webclient

i want to download some files from an webserver using an Backgroundworker. I already have this

```
WebClient req = new WebClient();

byte[] pbo = request.DownloadData(PathOnWebserver);
FileStream dwn = File.Create(LocalPath);
dwn.Write(pbo, 0, pbo.Length);
dwn.Close();`
```

In my first attempt, running in an WindowsFormapplication was succesfully.
Now i runned the Same code in an Wpf-Application and it throws an OutOfMemoryException.
So i googled about this problem but i didn't found an Solution that stores the Data until the full file has been downloaded.
I need this, because i have to work with this files some moments later and if i have corrupted Data, like if i close the Application, i can throw them into the trashcan.

Is there a simple way to get similar Code to run that provides a guarantee that the Data is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do

```
req.DownloadFile(PathOnWebserver, TempLocalPath); 
File.Move(TempLocalPath, LocalPath);
```

If TempLocalPath is on the same drive as LocalPath then Move is atomic because it just performs a rename. If you have a failure you just trash the temp file on startup. Programs like Chrome and Firefox do this exact method by adding `.partial` to the filename while the file is still downlaoding then doing a rename when complete.

Comment: I will give this a try! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck with the `Task` class provided by the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Below is a short mock up of a possible solution. You would obviously need to instantiate the variables you use when downloading the data such as `LocalPath` and `PathOnWebserver`.

```
// Call this method to start the download
private void DownloadData()
{
    // Create a TaskFactory on the current Thread; the UI thread
    TaskFactory UITaskFactory = 
        new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    // Create and start a Task that will download the data
    var DoDownloadTake = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Boolean success = false;
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            byte[] pbo = wc.DownloadData(PathOnWebserver);
            FileStream dwn = File.Create(LocalPath);
            dwn.Write(pbo, 0, pbo.Length);
            dwn.Close();
            success = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){} // Handles this however you'd like to.

        // Call a method on the UI thread to notify us the download completed
        UITaskFactory.StartNew(() => DataFinishedDownloading(success));
    });
}

// Once the data is finished downloading this method will be called
private void DataFinishedDownloading(Boolean success)
{
    if(success)
        ;// Do something with data at LocalPath
    else
        ;// Download failed
}
```